# php custom sorting function

Tags: php, sorting

How can I form a function that takes three inputs as integer and show them in descending order? I used this code but not working :)

```
function show_numbers(int $number1 = null, int $number2 = null, int $number3 = null) {
    if ($number1 < $number2 || $number1 < $number3) {
        if ($number2 < $number3) {
            return $message = "{$number1} - {$number2} - {$number3}";
        }
    } elseif ($number2 < $number1 || $number2 < $number3) {
        if ($number1 < $number3) {
            return $message = "{$number2} - {$number1} - {$number3}";
        }
    } elseif($number3 < $number1 || $number3 < $number2) {
        if ($number2 < $number1) {
            return $message = "{$number3} - {$number2} - {$number1}";
        }
    }
}

echo show_numbers(10, 5, 1);
```

Comment: [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Comment: On [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) there are many examples on how to use the sort function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)